# OOP Cookie Class

Tags: php, oop

i recently made a cookie class but unfortunatly it wasn't really OOP because i made the class do 2 different things. that is set/get the cookie and also store te cookie. and OOP means every class has its own operation. so i decided to rewrite my class but i am not able to let it work. here is how i tought i should do it.

i made a interface for the CRUD and a Class that implements this interface called CookieStorage. also i made a Cookie class that sets the cookie values etc. but now by creating this two classes it doesn't work because i get this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method CookieStorage::getName() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/library/lib/CookieStorage.php on line 27

below you can find my code. thanks in advance!

```
<?php

interface StorageInterface {
    public function set(Cookie $cookie);
    public function get(Cookie $cookie);
    public function update(Cookie $cookie);
    public function delete(Cookie $cookie);
}

class CookieStorage implements StorageInterface {

/**
 * constructor
 */
public function __construct() {

}

/**
 * Create cookie.
 */
public function set(Cookie $cookie) {
    return setcookie(   
        $this->getName(),
        $this->getValue(),
        $this->getTime(), 
        $this->getPath(), 
        $this->getDomain(), 
        $this->getSecure(), true 
    );
}

/**
 * Get cookie.
 */
public function get(Cookie $cookie) {
    return $_COOKIE[$this->getName()];
}

/**
 * Update cookie.
 */
public function update(Cookie $cookie) {
    return $this->update();
}

public function delete(Cookie $cookie) {
    return $this->delete();
}

}

?>
```

Comment: `$this->getName(),
                            $this->getValue(),
                            $this->getTime(), 
                            $this->getPath(), 
                            $this->getDomain(), 
                            $this->getSecure()` None of these are defined?

Comment: you have no getName method in your class, that's why you get that error

Comment: do i also have to get this methods defined in CookieStorage?

Comment: yes you have to define methods in CookieStorage class, unless Cookie Class has those methods and you want to use those, in that case change $this-> to $cookie->

Comment: GeoPhoenix you are great! that worked :D thanks alot!

Comment: "and OOP means every class has its own operation". Please don't blindly follow rules because they are the rules, practicality should dictate your decisions, not some book. If you're in the OO scene long enough, you'll see where it makes sense, and more importantly; where it doesn't.

Comment: Adding to what @BerryLangerak said, even making your class handle ALL cookie-related stuff (read, write, store, explode, eat..) isn't breaking "OO rules", it's actually the recommended practice. The "rule" you have in your head is probably about the methods (functions).

Comment: hmm its a little bit hard to tell whether do it this way or the other way because when i ask people for help because im new to OOP then everyone begins about the fact that a class may not have 2 operations but is made to do only 1 thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to use `$cookie->getName()`. `$this` points to the storage class, yet you want to store the properties of the cookie parameter instead.

**Update:**
Your call as mentioned in the comment is correct. If you pass your Cookie object, then in the `set` function of you `CookieStorage` you'll need to use `$cookie`, not `$this`.

Comment: yes that is correct but i tought if i used it like this it would work: 

$cookieStorage = new CookieStorage();
$cookieStorage->set($cookie);